# Powershell script remove | from csv file

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV file that is outputting data in this format:

```
  sitename      |         groupname          |        grouprole
```

--------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------

Administration     | Group1            | NewRole

Finance            | Group1            | NewRole

Default            | Group1            | NewRole

I am trying to remove the | marks and replace them with a ; delimiter.
I am already using: ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter ';'  -NoType| % {$_ -replace ' ',''}  to remove the padded spaces.
I tried using  % {$_ -replace '|',';'} to have it replace the | with ; so that it would format to a proper CSV file.  Instead the results were:

;s;i;t;e;n;a;m;e;|;g;r;o;u;p;n;a;m;e;|;g;r;o;u;p;r;o;l;e;

How do I go about removing the | in a CSV file and replacing it with a proper delimiter?

Comment: You need to escape `|`: `... -replace '\|',';'`, but this sounds a bit like an XY question - You say you have "a CSV file that is outputting data", but files don't output anything, they're just data on disk - how are you reading and displaying the contents of the file?

Comment: have you tried just using `Import-Csv`? it has a `-Delimiter` parameter ...